# MSI Installation should wait while product is running

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an MSI package for the product with minor fixes and I didn't want to distract user with closing application. I want to wait for the moment when user leave application.

I have an update program running under user privilegies that can execute in silent mode something like this

msiexec /i product.msi /quiet

but when msi install product it send WM_QUIT to it and program closed and user should reopen it. How can I postpone the execution of such command? Can I schedule installation?

Comment: I need to understand your situation better.  Can you just prompt the user in the application that a newer version is available and as them to launch it when they close the application?

Comment: Do you have an elevated priv running that msiexec command or something?   If so, you could look at the /jm ( instead of /i ) command to advertise ("bless") the MSI so that if the non-priv user launches the /i  it should install correctly.  ( Assuming it's designed correctly.)

Comment: 1) yes, I can prompt user that newer version is available, but here I want to research vairants without any user actions
2) I running under normal user priv (de elevated), I know that I can create service (running by admin) that can make installation after swithing on and before login, but also want to avoid it

Comment: I'm not really understanding your requirement so it's hard to give you advice.  But do be aware that if you launch MSI silently and put something in the installer to wait until the app is closed, you won't be able to install anything else at the same time because MSI implements a system wide mutex that limits one running install at a time.

Comment: Chrisopher what part of description is confusing you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to make your application "Restart Manager" aware.

Instead of WM_QUIT you register as being restart manager aware, and Windows Installer will send WM_QUERYENDSESSION/WM_ENDSESSION messages. You prepare the application for a graceful shutdown, save the users session or block application shutdown as appropriate and then your application is restarted automatically.

The MSDN documentation on the Restart Manager [Guidelines for Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will get you started.

Comment: thank you, this question is still actual for me and you get me a hope

Comment: good luck! I think Microsoft had a demo video on channel9 around the time of the Vista launch demoing the functionality, there might also be some sample code in the Windows SDK if you need additional help.